# How to debug beginners code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2 questions about my code. Why the program doesn't go in the second `if` statement. How can I end the loop?

```
from random import *

SecretNumber=randint(1,5)
Guess=int(input("Please enter Guess: "))
NumberofGuesses=1
SecretNumber=0

while Guess != SecretNumber:
    NumberofGuesses=NumberofGuesses+1
    if Guess>SecretNumber:
        print("Please insert a smaller number")
    else:
        print("Please insert a bigger number")

    if Guess==SecretNumber:
        print("Number of Guesses: {0}".format(NumberofGuesses))
```

Comment: To answer your title question re: how to debug beginner's code:  walk through the code by hand.  If necessary, put prints (or at the top do import pdb; pdb.set_trace() to allow you to single step through the code and check the values equal what you expect).  Among other things, you should hopefully see you only change guess once (outside the loop)

Comment: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: As a beginner you might be interested in the official [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 3):

Your second `if` is outside the `while` loop, so it won't get hit until you guesss the secret number.  The loop never ends because you never read another guess.

You also have a problem that you are overriding your random secret number with zero.

You need something like:

```
import random
SecretNumber=random.randint(1,5)

NumberofGuesses=0

while true:
    Guess=int(input("Please enter Guess: "))
    NumberofGuesses += 1

    if Guess == SecretNumber:
         break    # Got it!
    elif Guess>SecretNumber:
         print("Please insert a smaller number")
    else:
         print("Please insert a bigger number")

print("Number of Guesses: {0}".format(NumberofGuesses))
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're setting SecretNumber to 0. Remove it and it should work.